# Primefaces lazytable sorting change first sorting order

Tags: sorting, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

is there any way to allow, after the first request to sort a particular column, not to be listed first in ascending order, but first in descending order?

description:
If I need to sort the column in descending order, it is necessary to first click on the column in ascending order and only then reload the table with the sorted data as I require.
One not entirely nice solution that I use now is in the case of columns, where I require the reverse order, I simply swap the meaning ascending/descending when querying the DB. But the table does not show graphically correctly the arrow above the table in which direction I am sorting the data and it is necessary to intervene for the columns in CSS.

Is there a more elegant option?

Sorry for my easy English and thanks for any advice,
Venca.

Comment: Yes on the `datatable` look at the `sortBy` and `sortOrder` fields in the documentation: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datatable

Answer (score 1):

As @Melloware pointed in comment `datatable` has fields `sortBy` and `sortOrder` which can be used for sorting.

See example:

```xml
    <p:dataTable id="txnTable"
        value="#{chTransactionsForm.transactions}" var="res"
        sortMode="single" sortBy="#{res.activityDate}" sortOrder="DESCENDING"
        rows="#{referenceData.recordsPerPage}" rowKey="#{res._lineNumber}"
        lazy="true" resizableColumns="true"
        paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
        paginatorTemplate="#{referenceData.paginatorTemplate}">
   
        <p:column id="activityDate" headerText="#{msg.transDate}"
            sortBy="#{res.activityDate}" width="120">
            <h:outputText value="#{res.activityDate}">
                <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{referenceData.timezone}"
                    pattern="MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>
        ...
```